# Event listener for identify new elements in the page?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, event-listener, dom-events

I am trying to find a way to trigger an event when a new specific element will be created in the page.

For example, I want the my callback function
`function(){console.log(1);}` will be triggered if a new element named `#newElem` will be created in the page.

Any ideas how can I register this kind of events? 
How can I, for example, create an Event Listener for the parent element and trigger it if a new child appended?

Comment: Mutation Observer

Comment: @RandyCasburn Thanks. Just found it also.